# Delete conflicted with the Reference

Tags: c#, sql, database, reference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I got error “The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776269/i-got-error-the-delete-statement-conflicted-with-the-reference-constraint)

I am receiving the error

`The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint fk`

Is there away to automatically delete the row that is causing this reference conflict such as setting a property or such. To avoid first deleting the child and then going back and deleting the original row you wanted to delete?

Comment: You need to set the foreign key's delete option to CASCADE on delete

Comment: SQL-Server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973.aspx and here(with SSMS): http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2365/sql-server-foreign-key-update-and-delete-rules/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your table, specify ON DELETE CASCADE.

This sets up the delete action for the table to also delete referencing rows, if it is the parent.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on `delete cascade` to your table and the referencing row will be deleted automatically too.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the key to key table, the relation table first before deleting the original primary key record.